# Extracting tags and text between tags using regex on an string with XML tags

Tags: java, regex, xml

I am trying to extract both the tag and the text between the tags in a text file. I am trying to achieve this using regex (Not many xml tags are there).

below is what I have tried so far

```
     String txt="<DATE>December</DATE>";

        String re1="(<[^>]+>)"; // Tag 1
        String re2="(.*?)"; // Variable Name 1
        String re3="(<[^>]+>)"; // Tag 2

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
        if (m.find())
        {
            String tag1=m.group(1);
            String var1=m.group(2);
            String tag2=m.group(3);
            //System.out.print("("+tag1.toString()+")"+"("+var1.toString()+")"+"("+tag2.toString()+")"+"\n");

            System.out.println(tag1.toString().replaceAll("<>", ""));
            System.out.println(var1.toString());
        }
```

As an answer, I get:

```
<DATE>
December
```

How do I get rid of the `<>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to use regex to parse xml. Using a regex there is no way of identifying a complete element from opening to closing tag (a regex cannot "remember" a number of occurances).

However why your regex fails in this specific case:

In `re1`, `re2`, `re3` you choose the capturing group to include `<` and `>` (also you do not include the `/` in `re3`). You could simply change this

```
String re1="<([^>]+)>"; // Tag 1
String re2="([^<]*)"; // Variable Name 1
String re3="</([^>]+)>"; // Tag 2
```

or use a suitable regex to remove `<` and `>` form `tag1`:

```
System.out.println(tag1.toString().replaceAll("<|>", ""));
```

or

```
System.out.println(tag1.toString().replaceAll("[<>]", ""));
```

Comment: It works. But, It does not recognize any further tags in the sentence.  EG: `American Airlines made <TRIPS> 100 <TRIPS>  flights in <DATE> December </DATE>`  it only recognizes TRIPS and 100 but not the next tag

Comment: @Betafish: `<TRIPS>` is not closed by a `</TRIPS>` tag in your example. If you want to ignore that, you could use `re3 = "</?([^>]+)>"` or `re3 = re1`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex to parse markup syntax, such as XML, HTML, XHTML and so on.

[Many reasons are shown here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Instead, do yourself a favor and use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) and [XQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery).

Comment: yes, your right. But, I only have less tags in my text file (max 10 tags). Hence regex.